# How to give a special format to a number with auto_increment in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want to give a specific format to an users's id in MYSQL, but it must be auto_increment type. My idea is to do this: US01, US02, US03,US04...

I don't know how to do this type of ID, I'd greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Consider handing this at the application level - prefix and left pad the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoincrementing numbers in MySQL have either type `INT` or type `BIGINT`. You can't assign another data type to an autoincrementer. (So, it's not surprising you don't know how to do it, eh?)

You could, if you were working in MariaDB or in MySQL 5.7.5+, create a virtual (computed) column transforming your integer autoincrementer into the format you want. If your autoincrementing column were `user_id`, this would give you a virtual column with the id value you want.

```
  ALTER TABLE mytable 
   ADD COLUMN useridtext varchar(10) 
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
                (CONCAT('US', LPAD(user_id,8,'0')))
              PERSISTENT
```

makes a new virtual column, in MariaDB, named `useridtext`.  It contains values like `US00000001`, `US00000002`, and so forth.

The same could be done in any version of MySQL by creating a view of your table.

Comment: Beautiful and unknown, but i have a doubt ... How will mysql keep an updated value of the numerical id?. Should I have another column that be an incremental int?

Comment: My suggestion assumes `user_id` is an autoincrementing primary key. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Note that the support of using `AUTO_INCREMENT` is removed in Mariadb. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/